# Partial Ajax Pagination in cakePHP

Tags: ajax, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-1.3

I'm trying to add ajax pagination into a view of my application.
I followed this tutorial: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1600/Ajax-Pagination

So, in this tutorial you always reload the whole content of the view by clicking the pagination links.
But what I want is, that it only reloads the part of the site which includes the paginated data.

Comment: If you correctly follow the tutorial, the only part which will be reloaded is the element containing the model data. Did you included the `RequestHandler` in your controller's component and the `writeBuffer()` method in your view file? Maybe you might show us your controller and view code.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for myself:

I made a view which only contains the ajax pagination and included it via ajax request:

```
<?php $this->Html->scriptStart(array('inline' => false));?>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        <?php 
        echo $this->Js->request(array(
                'controller' => 'topics', 
                'action' => 'index', 
                $location['Location']['id']
            ), array(
                'async' => true,
                'update' => '#ajax_topics',
        ));
        ?>
    });
<?php $this->Html->scriptEnd();?>
```